# Как залить фон с углами

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Вот описание проблемы

[image: Тык]

Comment: "Просмотр вложений разрешен только со страниц нашего форума. Для просмотра вложения, перейдите по ссылке ниже."

Comment: Я не могу вставлять вложения, поэтому опубликовал ссылку на картинку http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/html/219487d1356934662-htmlerrorb.png

Comment: Если это дизайн будущего сайта, то может Вы его не будете делать?

Answer (score 1):

Простыми способами это точно не реализуется.

Как вариант: строку высотой 1пх продублировать то количество раз, какой размер скругления у вас задан. Строка будет нести в себе фон и бордюры по сторонам. В итоге получается такой вот, внешний скругленный угол:

```
<style>
.border {
    border-left: 1px yellow solid;
    border-right: 1px yellow solid;
    background: gray;
    height: 1px;
}
</style>

<div class='border' style='width: 100px;'></div>
<div class='border' style='width: 102px;'></div>
<div class='border' style='width: 104px;'></div>
<div class='border' style='width: 106px;'></div>
<div class='border' style='width: 108px;'></div>
<div class='border' style='width: 110px;'></div>
```